# Give different permissionson to folder and subfolder to different users

Tags: command-line, permissions

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to deeply comprehend giving permission for folders for different users.
I have three users Anton, Anna and John and they belong to the same group.
Lets imagine, Anton has a folder called parent that has three sub folders child1, child2, and child3

1. He wants everything in parent and its sub folders to be readable (not editable and not executable) by everyone (on the planet)
2. child1 can only be edited (not executed)  by group member (Anna, John and future members)
3. child2 is readable and editable(not executable) by only Anton (the folder owner)
4. child3 is not editable but executable by everyone (on the planet)

Is this possible to do using terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the terminal not only possible but also the quickest way to do so when it comes to many files and directories with multiple permission types.

First, let's refer to a quick [guide](https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html) to learn about the basics of permissions and permission values and types.

The relevant terminal command is `chmod "permissions" "filename"`.

For example: `chmod 777 foo` or `chmod 777 /foo/food`.

We must seperate this problem per file/directory and remember we have 3 types of permissions: creator user, group and others.
Highest permissions always beat lower ones (root > creator > group > others), thus applying only rules to a group with the creator won't always prevent the creator from doing operations defined by the group permission.

Overall what you want to set is this (if I understand the question correctly):

Parent- owner, group, others = `'r'` (4). [`444`]

C1- owner = non (0) or `'w'` (2), group = `'w'` (2), others = non (0). [`220`]

C2- owner = `'rw'` (6), group & others = non (0). [`600`]

C3- owner, group, others = `'x'` (1). [`111`]